# How to to do a List that contains just one attribute and not repeat in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to make a List that contains just the name of the City, no more. The citiets doesn't have to repeat, I need all the names of the city but without repeated names.

The Entity looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cities {
    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String city;
    private String[] loc;
    private String pop;
    private String state;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    String getLocation() {
        return loc[0] + " " + loc[1];
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String[] getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String[] loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public String getPop() {
        return pop;
    }

    public void setPop(String pop) {
        this.pop = pop;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cities{" +
                "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", loc=" + Arrays.toString(loc) +
                ", pop='" + pop + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I have my Repositoy like this:

```
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Entity.Cities;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository("citiesRepository")
public interface CitiesRepository extends MongoRepository<Cities, String> {
    public Cities findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
    public List<Cities> findByCity(String city);
    public List<Cities>  findAllByCity();
}
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Constant.ViewConstant;
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Entity.Cities;
import com.sbmongo.starbucks.Repository.CitiesRepository;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/starbucks")
public class CitiesController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("citiesRepository")
    private CitiesRepository citiesRepository;

    @GetMapping("/cities")
    public ModelAndView listCities(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.CITIES);
        mav.addObject("cities", citiesRepository.findAll());
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchCity")
    public ModelAndView searchCity(@RequestParam(name = "city", required = false)String city){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.CITIES);
        mav.addObject("cities", citiesRepository.findByCity(city.toUpperCase()));
        System.out.println(citiesRepository.findByCity(city.toUpperCase()));
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/sortAllCities")
    public void sortAllCities(){
        List<Cities> cities = citiesRepository.findAllByCity();
    }
}
```

But when I try to do this i throws me a IndexOutOfBoundsException.
I just want to show in the list the names of the cities and don't repeat the names.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting IOB exception?

Comment: @OmarFaroqueAnik
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
 at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getParameter(Parameters.java:217) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getBindableParameter(Parameters.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

To fill a List of unique names use Set, then loop and fill the new object.
If you need the key replace the Set with Map.

Hope this sample help

```
       List<Cities> citiesList = findAllByCity();
        Set<Cities> uniqueCities = new HashSet<>();
        citiesList.forEach(c ->{
            uniqueCities.add(c);
        });
```

Comment: I tried to do this in the Controller but it throws me a IndexOutOfBoundsException. I believe it's because the method to get the Cities names findAllByCity in the Repository doesn't work properly and I don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: So the problem is in cities list retrieval, not the loop?

Comment: I think so, because I can't get the cities names properly

Comment: You need to check the connection parameters and to be sure that there is data in the cities table, I think this may solve the issue. Add your yml or properties file content to the post